# Why are curl_multi_select and curl_multi_info_read contradicting each other?

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

When I run the below code it seems to me `curl_multi_select` and `curl_multi_info_read` are contradicting each other.  As I understand it `curl_multi_select` is supposed to be blocking until `curl_multi_exec` has a response but I haven't seen that actually happen.

```
$url = "http://google.com";
$ch  = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);

$mc = curl_multi_init();
curl_multi_add_handle($mc, $ch);

do {
  $exec = curl_multi_exec($mc, $running);
} while ($exec == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

$ready=curl_multi_select($mc, 100);
var_dump($ready);

$info = curl_multi_info_read($mc,$msgs);
var_dump($info);
```

this returns

```
int 1
boolean false
```

which seems to contradict itself.  How can it be ready and not have any messages?

The php version I'm using is 5.3.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically `curl_multi_select` blocks until there is something to read or send with `curl_multi_exec`. If you loop around `curl_multi_exec` without using `curl_multi_select` this will eat up 100% of a CPU core.
So `curl_multi_info_read` is used to check if any transfer has ended (correctly or with an error).

Code using the multi handle should follow the following pattern:

```
do
{
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($this->mh, $active);
}
while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK)
{
    curl_multi_select($this->mh);
    do
    {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($this->mh, $active);
    }
    while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    while ($info = curl_multi_info_read($this->mh))
    {
        $this->process_ch($info);
    }
}
```

See also: [Doing curl_multi_exec the right way](http://www.adrianworlddesign.com/Knowledge-Base/php/Download-content-with-cURL/Doing-curlmultiexec-the-right-way).

Comment: Weird. I had a simple `curl_multi_exec()` with a short `usleep()` before and changing to this approach doubled the total time it takes to fetch all URLs, the number of failed requests tripled and the CPU usage remained basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

From the [spec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php):

*Ask the multi handle if there are any messages or information from the individual transfers. Messages may include information such as an error code from the transfer or just the fact that a transfer is completed.*

The 1 could mean there is activity, but not necessarily a message waiting: in this case probably that some of your download data is available, but not all. The example in the [curl_multi_select](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php) doc explicitly tests for false values back from `curl_multi_info_read`.

Comment: If that is true it is even more confusing.  Why bother calling  `curl_multi_select` at all?  Wouldn't you just loop over `curl_multi_info_read`?

Comment: It is much more efficient looping in `curl_multi_select` instead of `curl_multi_info_read`.

Comment: Not if it doesn't actually block till there is a response.  I'm having to make more calls.  The example you linked to didn't even work for me until I commented out `curl_multi_select`.  In which case it worked perfectly.  I'm still looking for a good explanation for how `curl_multi_select` works because frankly it doesn't make any sense. What exactly is the other activity that is stopping the blocking? If that is true there should be a way to see it.